# Django two projects, same database

Tags: django, database, apache, mod-wsgi, multiple-projects

I try to set up two projects,
The first is a management project - it involves auth_user, sessions, writing to db.
The second project is a "serve content" project, it only read from the db, uses no sessions, users..
It rely on db data created in the first project, but does not change it.

The second project urls will be accessed **very** frequently. That's why I want to seperate the projects, with different subdomaons, and two apache instances, giving the second one more "power" (processes in wsgi deamon conf).

So what should I share between the projects? Same settings? SECRET_KEY?  Models?
I assume I should also remove session app.
Can I set django db to be in read only mode?